# Binding int variable as value in style

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to find how to bind an int variable as my value in style. Here is my simple xaml style.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonMenu">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
```

In the fourth row, I wanna change the value from 14 to my variable called **SizeVar** bud I can't find how to do it. I really tried googling but can't find anything that works for me. I know that I should do it somehow through binding but not exactly how.

I tried using different binding options but couldn't find one that works for me. My English is also not perfect so maybe it is possible that I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description I interpreted the following:

1. You have a XAML-file where in the Resources you want to contain a style called "ButtonMenu".
2. The variable that binds to the FontSize is called "SizeVar" and is contained in the DataContext, which is set.

With this, I tested it out and the following works.

In the View (XAML):

```
...
<Window.DataContext>
   <viewmodels:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonMenu">
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding SizeVar}"/>
   </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
   <Button
      Content="Test"
      Style="{DynamicResource ButtonMenu}"/>
</Grid>
...
```

In the associated ViewModel (C#):

```
private int _sizeVar;
public int SizeVar
{
   get => _sizeVar;
   set
   {
      _sizeVar = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}

public MainViewModel()
{
   SizeVar = 14;
}
```